# How would I group a list of appointments by date?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm returning a list of appointments.

Right now they look like this:

```
-Jan 1
--appointment @230
-Jan 1
--appointment @3
-Jan 1
--appointment @4
-Jan 2
--appointment @4
-Jan 2
--appointment @5
```

I'd like to return the list like

```
-Jan 1
--appointment @230
--appointment @3
--appointment @4
-Jan 2
--appointment @4
--appointment @5
```

The appointments have a "start_at" field which is a DateTime. Relatively simply. Jut not sure how to iterate over the collection and then grouping it in the sanest way.

Thanks.

User (is a user or a trainer)
has_many :appointments
has_many :trainer_appointments, :class_name => "Appointment", :foreign_key => "trainer_id"

Appointment

```
# Table name: appointments
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  trainer_id :integer
#  start_at   :datetime
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  user_id    :integer
```

Here's some play code:
u.trainer_appointments

```
=> [#<Appointment id: 6, trainer_id: 1, start_at: "2012-11-18 13:08:00", created_at: "2012-10-17 02:01:42", updated_at: "2012-10-17 02:01:42", user_id: 2>, #<Appointment id: 7, trainer_id: 1, start_at: "2012-11-18 13:08:00", created_at: "2012-10-17 02:02:00", updated_at: "2012-10-17 02:02:00", user_id: 2>, #<Appointment id: 8, trainer_id: 1, start_at: "2012-11-24 13:08:00", created_at: "2012-10-17 02:03:28", updated_at: "2012-10-17 02:03:28", user_id: 2>]
```

Returns 3 appointments. Two are on the same day. 1 on a different day.

Would like to return that in a way where it's grouped by a Date. 
I tried something like this to figure it out but got lost:

```
u.trainer_appointments.collect {|each| each.start_at}.uniq.collect {|each| u.trainer_appointments.find_by_start_at(each.to_date.beginning_of_day..each.to_date.end_of_day)}
```

Which returned two appointments. Between both dates. Missing the 2nd on the first day.

I know that code is wrong on so many levels. I was just trying to toy with the iteration. Didn't get what I wanted though. Probably because the uniq limits the return size in some way even though I was expecting a range to be returned in the final array.

I'm not sure what actual structure I need to iterate over the groupings. This isn't my expertise. An array inside an array grouped? How would I iterate over that in a view?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your code look like?  Easier to try and help if we see what you are doing, rather than just the result and desired result.

Comment: Added examples. Thanks and sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `group_by` on your collection.

The [Ruby implementation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) requires the expression passed into it evaluates to a boolean.

The [Rails implementation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) allows you to pass in a column and it groups it by that column.

Your code should look like this

```
u.trainer_appointments.
  collect {|a| a.start_at}.
  uniq.collect {|b| 
    u.trainer_appointments.
    group_by(b.to_date.beginning_of_day..b.to_date.end_of_day)
  }
```

Replace `find_by_start_at` with `group_by`

**EDIT**: Scoping it up!

```
# in User model (or the model for current_user)
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :mine, where(:trainer_id => current_user)
  scope :days!, where(:start_at.to_date.beginning_of_day)
  # the ! is there because "days" is a Ruby method
end

# in controller...
@client_appointments = @client.appointments.mine.group_by(&:days!)
```

Note: I am not certain if it's `group_by(days!)`, `group_by(:days!)` or `group_by(&:days!)`. You may have to play around with it to see what works for you.

Comment: Thanks your comment shed light on how to do it in a nicer way. I ended up doing something like this:     @client_appointments = @client.appointments.find(:all, :conditions => {:trainer_id => current_user}).group_by {|a| a.start_at.to_date.beginning_of_day }

Comment: you may also use scopes to make the code more readable. I have edited my answer as to how this could be done using the current line of code you sent in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using the grouping features of a database, the easiest way is to use chunk:

```
require 'date'

# Make some test data
Appointment = Struct.new(:start_at)
data = ['2012-01-01 14:30', '2012-01-01 15:00', '2012-01-01 16:00',
 '2012-01-02 16:00', '2012-01-02 17:00']

appointments = data.map do |time|
  Appointment.new DateTime.parse(time)
end

# Use chunk to group array elements
appointments.
  sort { |a,b| b.start_at <=> a.start_at }. # always sort before chunking
  chunk { |appt| appt.start_at.to_date }. # chunk on day of the appointment
  each do |day, appts| # chunk emits two-element arrays
    puts
    puts "Day " + day.to_s
    appts.each { |appt| puts appt.start_at.strftime('%H:%M') }
  end
```

Output:

```
Day 2012-01-02
17:00
16:00

Day 2012-01-01
16:00
15:00
14:30
```

Comment: Holy crap Chunk is complicated. I get it though. Thanks for teaching me. I'm going to go with the ActiveRecord group_by for ease but if I ever use something like Mongoid then I know one way to do it if the database doesn't support a group_by.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the following:

```
    @client_appointments = @client.appointments.find(:all, :conditions => {:trainer_id => current_user}).group_by {|a| a.start_at.to_date.beginning_of_day }
```

And then iterating over it like so:

```
- @client_appointments.sort.each do |month, appointments|
  %h2
    = month.to_s(:day_month)
  = render appointments
```